# Creating a Search Bar to query two database columns at once

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to create a search bar that searches two or more database columns. I am creating a phone directory that searches for a person's first and last name or any part of there name really.

As of right now my search bar (TextBox1) only allows the user to search one column on the database at a time.

Issue/Expected Result: The user inputs a last name of Williams it comes back with all of the Williams in the database under the Last_Name column. I want the users to be able to input a first and last name(ex: John Williams) and it filters out for both columns(Last_Name, First_Name) as of right now if the user inputs First and Last in (TextBox1) it comes back with nothing. I believe it is my query that is wrong but i'm not sure what needs to be changed to allow that type of filtering.Any guidance would be much appreciated thank you.

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin: auto; align-content:center; text-align:center;" placeholder="Enter A Name or Number" Height="43px" Width="412px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myconnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Last_Name], [First_Name], [Telephone], [Cell_Phone]  FROM [Person_Search] WHERE (([Cell_Phone] LIKE '%' + @Cell_Phone + '%')  OR ([First_Name] LIKE '%' + @First_Name + '%')  OR ([Telephone] LIKE '%' + @Telephone + '%') OR ([Last_Name] LIKE '%' + @Last_Name + '%'))">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Cell_Phone" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="First_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Telephone" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Last_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one simple way:
In your table create a one more column as UserName and insert the combine value of first and last name e.g 'John Williams'.
And in your where condition make one more Usename like '%@searchText%'

Comment: That worked for me. Is this how normal search bars are used with db's or am I just doing a newbie deal.